# Xcode - Create a NSMutableArray consisting of an entity and its attributes

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, entities

I have an entity called "People" with 2 attributes, I need to add an entity to full Array

Something like:

self.personaDetail.nombre = self.textNombre.text; 
[self._personas addObject: self.personaDetail.nombre];

Can you help?

Thank you, greetings.

Comment: self.personaDetail.nombre=self.textNombre.text;
self.personaDetail.precio=self.textprecio.text;

[_personas addObject:personaDetail];
self.viewResumen.text=[_personas objectAtIndex:0];

me an exception occurs:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Thank you, greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add an instance of `People` into a `NSMutableArray` just do this:

```
NSMutableArray *peopleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[peopleArray addObject:person1];
```

Or if you want to add just "his" name do this:

```
[peopleArray addObject:person1.nombre];
```

Or:

```
[peopleArray addObject:[person1 nombre]];
```